# how should I debug using gdb? where to see the results?

Tags: ros, gdb, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be very trivial but I have problem with gdb debugging. I don't know how should I see xterm window when I launch the nodes using gdb.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303468/how-should-i-debug-using-gdb?-where-to-see-the-results?/) by [b.slmn](https://answers.ros.org/users/37535/b.slmn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-09-16**:
There's not enough detail here for us to help. Please edit your question to add the commands that you're running, and the output that you do see. If you're using a launch file please include that launch file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case you haven't, take a look at [How to Roslaunch Nodes in Valgrind or GDB](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB).

Especially the *run your node in gdb in a **new [..] window*** variants of the prefixes, such as:

- `launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"`: run your node in a gdb in a separate xterm window, manually type run to start it
- `launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args"`: run your node in gdb in the same xterm as your launch without having to type run to start it

> I don't know how should I see xterm window when I launch the nodes using gdb.

If you already tried the two `launch-prefix`es I list above, but still can't find the window, make sure it is not being spawned *behind* the terminal you use to `roslaunch` everything in. That has happened to me some times and it can make for a confusing 5 minutes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2